# Is there a property for log(n)/n?

Tags: logarithms

I found a small exercise which I couldn't figure what to do, so I found a solution. Then I tried to understand it and everything went well until I got to this part:

$$\frac{1}{8} = \frac{\log(n)}{n}$$

Then it just skipped and say that the answer was $n = 43$. I was wondering if there is some kind of property for $\log (n) / n$ I don't know about. Or otherwise, how was this solved?

EDIT: This is the exercise
Suppose we are comparing implementations of insertion sort and merge sort on the
same machine. For inputs of size n, insertion sort runs in 8n2 steps, while merge
sort runs in 64n lg n steps. For which values of n does insertion sort beat merge
sort?

And this was the solution given:
    $$8n^2 = 64n \log(n)$$
    $$n^2 = 8n \log(n)$$
    $$n = 8 \log(n)$$
$$\frac{1}{8} = \frac{log(n)}{n}$$

Comment: If $n=1$ you get $0$... is there something missing?

Comment: I don't follow :/

Comment: @Ant100: I think Tom's comment is about the lack of parentheses

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, in the book there are no parentheses.

Comment: I think this must be a logarithm base smaller than $2$, otherwise the listed solution of $n=63$ is false...

Comment: @Ant100: but when you write inline and don't use LaTeX, it is ambiguous whether you are asking about $\log(n/n)$ or $\log(n)/n$. Using LaTeX, you would not need to use parentheses: $\dfrac{\log n}{n}$.

Comment: In order for your solution of $n=63$ to be correct, the base of the logarithm must be: $$b=3^{16/63} \times 7^{8/63}$$ A rather unusual base!! Are you sure that you're not given more information?

Comment: I'll edit question with exercise and solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take your amended question, which asks us to solve the inequality:

$$8n^{2}<64 n \log_{2}(n)$$

We can therefore divide both sides by $64n$ to get:

$$\frac{n}{8}<\log_{2}(n)$$

This has to be solved by numerical methods and we see that we have (by Mathematica):

$$1.1<n\lesssim43.5593$$

And we note that $n$ must be an integer so we have:

$$\lceil 1.1 \rceil=2 <n < 43 = \lfloor 43.5593\rfloor$$

Comment: Indeed; the given answer of 63 could be a typo for 43, influenced by the presence of 64 in the equation.

Comment: @Théophile I'm terrible sorry I believe you are right, this was a horrible typo.

Comment: @Shaktal: I'm not sure how you get to n < 43, is it like a convention?

Comment: @Ant100 One way of arriving at it is the Newton-Raphson iterative method, which is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method). This equation doesn't have a elementary closed form as it is a transcendental equation, but its solutions can be expressed as exponentials of product logs. I got to it by simply using the following Mathematica code: `Reduce[n/8 < Log[2,n],n]`

Comment: An exact solution can be expressed in terms of the Lambert W-function.